# How to subdivide Excel Column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, table-styles, column

I'm a beginner in Excel and need some help with creating a table.

How would I subdivide the header of a column into two columns underneath it that could each contain data? That if, if I have a header that looks like |random title|, how would I divide the larger column into |random title| with
|sec1||sec2| directly underneath?

Thanks in advance

The image of how I want to subdivide my columns:
[image: The image of how I want to subdivide my columns]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: merge columns together with home>merge